# Download CSV function does not work for IOS phones

Tags: javascript

The function I created works for Chrome,Firefox and Safari, I am having difficulties as to why it's not working for the iphone. Here is my code:

```js
    downloadCSV = function(content, fileName, mimeType) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream';

      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10
        navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([content], {
          type: mimeType
        }), fileName);
      } else if (URL && 'download' in a) { //html5 A[download]
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {
          type: mimeType
        }));
        a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      } else {
        location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(content); // only this mime type is supported
      }
    }
```

On all browsers mentioned it successfully converts into a downloadable csv but for the iphone it becomes a .txt file which has the string for the csv. I was hoping someone here encountered a similar issue and was able to make a solution.